# Modifying SOAP XML namespace with Savon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, soap, savon

I'm attempting to modify one of the namespaces in my Savon SOAP call. Here is how my request looks:

```
HTTPI GET request to www.intg.pathway.verosapps.com (excon)
SOAP request: https://www.intg.pathway.verosapps.com/VerosPathway.svc
SOAPAction: "urn:IVerosPathway/VerosPathway_Ping", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 434
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <VerosPathway_Ping>
      <request>
        <Credentials>
          <UserId>*username*</UserId>
          <Password>*password*</Password>
        </Credentials>
      </request>
    </VerosPathway_Ping>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've had to do a ton of tweaking since this company expects it's clients to use .NET for their SOAP interaction and we are using Ruby. I am extremely close to getting the format correct, but I need to do one of two things in the Envelope section:

1. Change "xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" to "xmlns:wsdl="http://tempuri.org/"
2. **OR** remove "xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" completely.

Here is my Savon call:

```
apiClient = Savon.client(endpoint: "https://www.intg.pathway.verosapps.com/VerosPathway.svc", env_namespace: :soapenv, namespace_identifier: nil, logger: Rails.logger, log_level: :debug, log: true, :pretty_print_xml => true, ssl_version: :TLSv1, wsdl: 'https://www.intg.pathway.verosapps.com/VerosPathway.svc?wsdl')
```

If I add the following line to my Savon call:

```
namespaces: {"xmlns:wsdl" => "http://tempuri.org/"}
```

then my request looks like this:

```
HTTPI GET request to www.intg.pathway.verosapps.com (excon)
    SOAP request: https://www.intg.pathway.verosapps.com/VerosPathway.svc
    SOAPAction: "urn:IVerosPathway/VerosPathway_Ping", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 434
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://tempuri.org/">
      <soapenv:Body>
        <VerosPathway_Ping>
          <request>
            <Credentials>
              <UserId>*username*</UserId>
              <Password>*password*</Password>
            </Credentials>
          </request>
        </VerosPathway_Ping>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

So in this case I would just need to remove the "xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" line.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out. All I needed to do was add the following line to my Savon call:

```
namespace: ""
```

So my final Savon call looks like:

```
apiClient = Savon.client(
    endpoint: "https://www.intg.pathway.verosapps.com/VerosPathway.svc",
    namespace: "", 
    env_namespace: :soapenv, 
    namespace_identifier: nil, 
    logger: Rails.logger, 
    log_level: :debug, 
    log: true, 
    :pretty_print_xml => true, 
    ssl_version: :TLSv1, 
    wsdl: 'https://www.intg.pathway.verosapps.com/VerosPathway.svc?wsdl'
)
```

Answer (score 5):

you can simply pass the hash with the options as below:

```
client = Savon.client(
     wsdl: "https://example.com?wsdl",
     log: true,
     log_level: :debug,
     pretty_print_xml: true,
     namespace_identifier: :mes,
     namespaces: {"xmlns:mes" => "http://example.com/messages/","xmlns:glob"=>"http://example.com/globals"}                      
)
```